# Center text inside font icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I have a font icon which will be right below some text. I would like the text to be in the middle of the icon (inside). If I use measures such as padding to push the text it would be a bad solution because the text might move depending on size and other elements around.

http://jsfiddle.net/gkAFD/

HTML:

```
<i class="fi-cloud"></i>
<span>Text</span>
```

CSS:

```
i {
  font-size: 63px;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: inline` and `vertical-align:middle` to your icon.

```
i {
    font-size: 63px;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkAFD/2/)

Comment: Actually I wanted it INSIDE the the cloud not just centered right next to it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible as both elements are inline. The closest I could get -> http://jsfiddle.net/gkAFD/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
i {
    font-size: 63px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
    color: red;
    margin-left: -45px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gkAFD/3/)

Comment: Please update the fiddle so I can see it. I want the text right inside the cloud, however.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to avoid. I could just position it with margin or padding but that will not be very flexible...

Comment: @user3704920, you can play with `position: absolute;`. something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/gkAFD/4/

Comment: Vertical-align is not really doing anything there and the text is not centered. This is a tough one.